# g_test_set_nonfatal_assertions() still Aborted (core dump) when using glib test framework

Tags: c, testing, glib

I am writing tests using the glib testing framework. They have assertions such as g_assert_true, which in their documentation says:

> Debugging macro to check that an expression is true.
>   If the assertion fails (i.e. the expression is not true), an error message is logged and the application is either terminated or the testcase marked as failed.
>   See g_test_set_nonfatal_assertions().

g_test_set_nonfatal_assertions() is defined as:

> Changes the behaviour of g_assert_cmpstr(), g_assert_cmpint(), g_assert_cmpuint(), g_assert_cmphex(), g_assert_cmpfloat(), g_assert_true(), g_assert_false(), g_assert_null(), g_assert_no_error(), g_assert_error(), g_test_assert_expected_messages() and the various g_test_trap_assert_*() macros to not abort to program, but instead call g_test_fail() and continue. (This also changes the behavior of g_test_fail() so that it will not cause the test program to abort after completing the failed test.) Note that the g_assert_not_reached() and g_assert() are not affected by this. This function can only be called after g_test_init().

This implies by calling g_test_set_nonfatal_assertions, rather than the test program to shut down it should continue running, it should continue running and mark the testcase as failed. However I have the following code snippet:

```
    void test_subscribe(mfixture* mf, gconstpointer ignored)
{
    g_assert_true(FALSE);
}

void test_test(mfixture* mf, gconstpointer ignored)
{
}


int main(int argc, char **argv){ 
    g_test_init(&argc, &argv, NULL);
    g_test_set_nonfatal_assertions ();

    g_test_add ("/set1/subscribe test", mfixture, NULL,message_setup, test_subscribe, message_teardown); 
    g_test_add ("/set1/test test", mfixture, NULL,message_setup, test_test, message_teardown); 


    return g_test_run(); 
}
```

I get the following output:

> ERROR:HubSubscriptions_test.c:32:test_subscribe: FALSE
>   make: *** [test-all] Aborted (core dumped)

Given the documentation you would expect it not to be Aborted. It seems to me that g_test_set_nonfatal_assertions() is just not working. Does anyone know if this is an existing bug, or if I am missing a step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [a known issue](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=722648) that cannot be easily fixed without actually running each separate test unit in a separate process.